# How to recompile gem native extensions in vendor?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, c, gemfile, vendor

I have a rails application and need to patch and recompile the C code of a gem.

So... basically what I want to do is:

Go to `vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rugged-0.21.2/ext/rugged/rugged_branch_collection.c`

Do a patch

and recompile the C code.

I dont want to mess with the Gemfile or Gemfile.lock.

It has to be compiled as --deployment.